# Is the Dirichlet function $f \equiv 1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

[image: tegra]

Not quite sure how to see III. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No it's not Riemann integrable, because it is discontinuous almost everywhere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability

Comment: I'd say I and II are true. Because $f(x)=0$ a.e., the Lebesgue integral will be zero. As 79037662 mentioned, the function is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Have you tried to show it yourself?

Comment: For III, the Lebesgue integral is zero, the Riemann integral doesn't exist.

Comment: @ 79037662 Thank you for the help. Just wondering if I could see it the other way around, i.e. it is continuous almost everywhere since the discontinuities are just the rationals?  thank you !

Comment: It's discontinuous at every point except $0$.  For any irrational $x$, there is a sequence of rationals that converges to $x$, (think of the decimal expansion of $x$).

Comment: @stevengerrard Except it's discontinuous at the irrationals as well. Any sequence of rationals converging to an irrational has $\lim f(x)=\text{irrational}$ but $f(\text{irrational})=0$

Comment: @ Peter Foreman  haha! Silly me. you are correct. I see it now!!! Thank you guys. By the way, this is not Dirichlet function, is it?

Comment: It's easy to see $f$ is not Riemann integrable on any $[a,b].$ Just note all the upper sums equal $b-a$ and all the lower sums are $0.$